# FFMPEG reduce dynamic range (VLC port ask)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player

Is there a way to do the exactly same thing as the image below (VLC) but using FFMPEG? I want it with FFMPEG to automate some jobs with batch files.

[image: Image 01]

In VLC, alongside the settings in the above image, I also enable the Dynamic Range Compressor.

[image: Image 02]

My settings for the compressor filter in VLC are:

- RMS/PEAK: 0
- ATTACK: 15ms
- RELEASE: 300ms
- THRESHOLD: -25dB
- COMPRESSION RATIO: 20.0 to 1
- KNEE RADIUS: 1.0dB
- MAKEUP GAIN: 15.0dB

Thanks in advance.